# VM fails to start after reboot in virtual box running on a Linux host

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, virtualization

I am new to Linux and trying to learn it in any possible way I could. So what I have done is - I have dual booted Ubuntu and Windows with Ubuntu on a separate HDD which is working fine. The issue I face is with Virtual machines that I am trying to set up on Ubuntu using Virtual box. Whenever I create a new machine it completes fine but after the restart, I am faced with different errors - sometimes these are kernel panic and at others it is something related to permissions.
Although machines will work fine initially until they are restarted. This issue happens with both - windows and Linux machines and I am unable to figure out how to get around this. My purpose of setting VMs was to learn and explore Linux but this issue is making it seem like a difficult task as there seems to be no docs related to this issue online.

Can anyone suggest me what could be the issue or point to any articles or reference docs that talk about setting up working virtual machines on Linux.

Comment: Are the Host machines or the guest machines breaking?

Comment: These are VMs, host is fine